# Does there exist an uncountably large set of sets of natural numbers $S$ such that, for all pairs of elements in $S$, one is a subset of the other?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Does there exist an uncountably large set of sets of natural numbers $S$ such that, for all pairs of elements in $S$, one is a subset of the other?
For example, there’s $\{\{\},\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\ldots\}$ which has the property, but is only countably large.